# Error in converting txt to xlsx using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

My code is following.

```
import csv
import openpyxl

import sys


def convert(input_path, output_path):
    """
    Read a csv file (with no quoting), and save its contents in an excel file.
    """
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]

    with open(input_path) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):
            for col_index, value in enumerate(row):
                ws.cell(row=row_index, column=col_index).value = value

    wb.save(output_path)


def main():
    try:
        input_path, output_path = sys.argv[1:]
    except ValueError:
        print 'Usage: python %s input_path output_path' % (sys.argv[0],)
    else:
        convert(input_path, output_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "txt2xlsx.py", line 33, in <module> 
    main() 
  File "txt2xlsx.py", line 29, in main 
    convert(input_path, output_path) 
  File "txt2xlsx.py", line 18, in convert 
    ws.cell(row=row_index, column=col_index).value = value 
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 350, in cell 
    column = get_column_letter(column) 
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\__init__.py", line 100, in get_column_letter 
    raise ValueError("Invalid column index {0}".format(idx)) 
ValueError: Invalid column index 0
```

I think I have installed openpyxl correctly.

And I remember I was using this program without any problem before. I recently bought a new computer so maybe this is a PC configuration issue.. But I can't figure out.

Comment: Do the columns index in openpyxl starts from 0 or 1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are using **openpyxl 2.0.0 +** ,according to [changelog for Openpyxl 2.0.0](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changes.html#id119) -

> Cells are referenced with 1-indexing: A1 == cell(row=1, column=1)

The rows and columns index start at 1. So you should make your `enumerate()` function start at 1 as well. Example -

```
    for row_index, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        for col_index, value in enumerate(row, 1):
            ws.cell(row=row_index, column=col_index).value = value
```

Your particular code would work in openpyxl version less than 2.0.0 , it fails because of the above mentioned change in version 2.0.0 .

Comment: @Anand_S_Kumar Thank you! Would it be enough to just replace the three lines in my original code starting from "for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):"  with your three lines of code?

Comment: Or should I do something else, too?

Comment: That should be enough.

Comment: Sure I will. Thank you again!

Comment: @Anand_S_Kumar    I accepted your answer. Thank you again!  By the way,  I have another follow-up question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216635/converting-txt-to-xlsx-while-setting-the-cell-property-for-number-cells-as-numbe        Could you have a look?

Comment: Yes, just now saw it :) , I am checking it