# MemoryError while converting txt to xlsx

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

Related questions:
1. [Error in converting txt to xlsx using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200127/error-in-converting-txt-to-xlsx-using-python?lq=1)

2. [Converting txt to xlsx while setting the cell property for number cells as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216635/converting-txt-to-xlsx-while-setting-the-cell-property-for-number-cells-as-numbe/)

My code is

```
    import csv
    import openpyxl

    import sys


    def convert(input_path, output_path):
        """
        Read a csv file (with no quoting), and save its contents in an excel file.
        """
        wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]

        with open(input_path) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
            for row_index, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
                for col_index, value in enumerate(row, 1):
                    ws.cell(row=row_index, column=col_index).value = value
        print 'hello world'

        wb.save(output_path)

        print 'hello world2'


    def main():
        try:
            input_path, output_path = sys.argv[1:]
        except ValueError:
            print 'Usage: python %s input_path output_path' % (sys.argv[0],)
        else:
            convert(input_path, output_path)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

This code works, except for some input files. I couldn't find what the difference is between the input txt that causes this problem and input txt that doesn't.

My first guess was encoding. I tried changing the encoding of the input file to UTF-8 and UTF-8 with BOM. But this failed.

My second guess was it used literally too much memory. But my computer has SSD with 32 GB RAM.

So perhaps this code is not fully utilizing the capacity of this RAM?

How can I fix this?

[image]
Edit: I added that line 
    print 'hello world'
and
    print 'hello world2'
to check if all the parts before 'hello world' are run correctly.

I checked the code prints 'hello world', but not 'hello world2'

So, it really seems likely that
    wb.save(output_path)

is causing the problem.

Comment: how big is the file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  One is 19MB and another is 32MB. Both fail.

Comment: I think it is safe to say that you have enough ram then, it is always on the save you get the error?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham   What does "one the save you get the error" mean? Maybe I don't understand this because of English..

Comment: I mean does the error only happen when `wb.save(output_path)` is executed, from the current traceback that seems to be what is happening

Comment: @PadraicCunningham   It seems you are right. I edited my question. I checked and confirmed wb.save(output_path) is causing the problem.

Comment: can you upload a bad file somewhere? Also is there any threshold you seem to get to sizewise that causes the errors?

Comment: 20 MB of text can mean a much bigger xlsx. Have you tried inserting a break when row_index is 100 (for example)?

Comment: I could confirm that when I reduce the size of the txt file, then it works. But maybe I deleted something that was really causing the problem while deleting a bunch of the text in the text file. The txt file has 150000 rows. Excel's maximum rows is more than 1,000,000. So this shouldn't be a problem is RAM is enough.. I think. So confusing....

Answer (score 1):

openpyxl has optimised modes for reading and writing large files.
`wb = Workbook(write_only=True)` will enable this.

I'd also recommend that you install lxml for speed. This is all covered in the documentation.

Comment: @Charlie_Clark Thank you for your response. By the way, how should I edit the code to write "wb = Workbook(write_only=True)"    ?    I tried replacing "wb = openpyxl.Workbook()"   with  "wb = Workbook(write_only=True)"   and with ""wb = openpyxl.Workbook(write_only=True)""    but both failed.

Comment: Sorry, without the code and files we can't help you any more than that. There must be something else going on.

Comment: One thing that could might be a problem is if each cell has a unique string. But even then with 32GB that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Below are three alternatives:

**RANGE FOR LOOP**

Possibly, the two `enumerate()` calls may have a memory footprint as indexing must occur in a nested for loop. Consider passing csv.reader content into a list (being subscriptable) and use `range()`. Though admittedly even this may not be efficient as starting in Python 3 each `range()` call (compared to deprecated `xrange`) generates its own list in memory as well.

```
with open(input_path) as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)

  row = []
  for data in reader:
      row.append(data)

  for i in range(len(row)):
      for j in range(len(row[0])):
          ws.cell(row=i, column=j).value = row[i][j]
```

**OPTIMIZED WRITER**

[OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells) even warns that scrolling through cells even without assigning values will retain them in memory. As a solution, you can use the [Optimized Writer](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/optimized.html) using above `row` list produced from csv.reader. This route appends entire rows in a write-only workbook instance:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()

i = 0
for irow in row:
   ws.append(['%s' % j for j in row[j]])
   i += 1

wb.save('C:\Path\To\Outputfile.xlsx')
```

**WIN32COM LIBRARY**

Finally, consider using the built-in win32com library where you open the csv in Excel and save as an [xlsx or xls workbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx). Do note this package is only for Python Windows installations.

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')

# OPEN CSV DIRECTLY INSIDE EXCEL
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(input_path)
excel.Visible = False
outxl=r'C:\Path\To\Outputfile.xlsx'

# SAVE EXCEL AS xlOpenXMLWorkbook TYPE (51)
wb.SaveAs(outxl, FileFormat=51)
wb.Close(False)
excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are fews points you can consider:

1. Check `/tmp` folder, default folder where tmp files for created;
2. Your code is utilizing complete space in that folder. Either increase that folder or you can change `tmp` file path while creating workbook;
3. I use in memory for performing my task and it worked.

Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import csv
import io
import sys
import traceback
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook


fileNames=sys.argv[1]

try:
    f=open(fileNames, mode='r')
    workbook = Workbook(fileNames[:-4] + '.xlsx',{'in_memory': True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    workbook.use_zip64()
    rowCnt=0
    #Create the bold style for the header row
    for line in f:
        rowCnt = rowCnt + 1
        row = line.split("\001")
        for j in range(len(row)):
            worksheet.write(rowCnt, j, row[j].strip())
    f.close()
    workbook.close()
    print ('success')
except ValueError:
    print ('failure')
```